# Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, macos, mysql-5.7, macos-monterey

While installing a new ruby version through RVM my `mysql` got updated from 5.7 to 5.8. My application is not supports 5.8 and hence trying to downgrade `mysql` version back to 5.7.

But couldn't do it successfully.

```
# Stopped currently running mysql
brew services stop mysql

# uninstall mysql
brew uninstall mysql

# removed old config files
sudo rm -rf /opt/homebrew/var/mysql

# install required version
# brew install mysql@5.7
```

But I can see a warning message as well `post-install step did not complete successfully`

```
2023-09-14T13:53:56.278342Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2023-09-14T13:53:56.281246Z 0 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /opt/homebrew/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
2023-09-14T13:53:56.351496Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=45790
2023-09-14T13:53:56.366220Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables.
2023-09-14T13:53:56.423706Z 0 [ERROR] unknown variable 'mysqlx-bind-address=127.0.0.1'
2023-09-14T13:53:56.423724Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully
You can try again using:
  brew postinstall mysql@5.7
```

I tried running `brew postinstall mysql@5.7` But same error returned

```
==> Postinstalling mysql@5.7
==> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql@5.7/5.7.43/bin/mysqld --initialize-insecure --user=mike --basedir=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql@5.7/5.7.43 --datadir=/opt/homebrew/var/mysql --tmpdir=/tmp
Last 15 lines from /Users/mike/Library/Logs/Homebrew/mysql@5.7/post_install.01.mysqld:
2023-09-14 19:32:32 +0530

/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql@5.7/5.7.43/bin/mysqld
--initialize-insecure
--user=mike
--basedir=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql@5.7/5.7.43
--datadir=/opt/homebrew/var/mysql
--tmpdir=/tmp

2023-09-14T14:02:32.051634Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2023-09-14T14:02:32.052340Z 0 [ERROR] --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting.
2023-09-14T14:02:32.052351Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting

Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully
You can try again using:
  brew postinstall mysql@5.7
```

But I can see correct version of mysql is installed

```
mysql -V
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.43, for osx10.17 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

I can even start mysql service

But when I try to do `mysql_secure_installation` It won't allow me to setup password for root user.

```
mysql_secure_installation


Securing the MySQL server deployment.

Enter password for user root:
Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

I tried multiple solutions and re-iterated the same flow. But still stuck at the same place

Comment: If you have to use different versions of MySQL I would really recommend that you use a Docker container - using Homebrew like this is not going to be a viable long term solution.